# Campground data or maps

Tags: data-request, geospatial

I am seeking to get data or map that has campground in the United State but more specifically Colorado. They can be either on the internet, download data, or have maps that done by someone who did the mapping.

I am looking at the Cottonwood Lake campground which lacks the information for me to gather the information. This campground is part of the USDA US Forest Service.

Comment: Have you looked at usgs.gov and similar sites?

Comment: No, but have been to US Forest Service.. and some other third party that don't really help much.

Comment: Check out usgs.gov and let us know if you still don't find anything. I'd USGS is probably the best source of govt maps.

Comment: http://www.wildlifeviewingareas.com/wv-app/ParkDetail.aspx?ParkID=203

Comment: @Mapperz   -Bingo !  not bad but doesn't have the faculty map as I need to check. to review it.

Answer (score 3):

The Forest Service (USDA) maintains a WMS url of recreation sites on public lands here:

http://apps.fs.usda.gov/arcx/rest/services/EDW/EDW_RecreationOpportunities_01/MapServer

This dataset does not contain recreation sites on most BLM, National Park, or other lands other than those administered by the forest service, but it is a pretty great collection nonetheless.

Comment: That is good too !

Answer (score 2):

Slew of resources that contain GIS in .shp, .kml, as well as details and maps in .pdf:
[Colorado Parks and Wildlife - Administrative Boundary Data](http://www.arcgis.com/home/group.html?id=a9490456f04f4a3aad8ff590ba5de33d)
[Department of Local Affair State of Colorado GIS Directory](http://dola.colorado.gov/gis-cms/content/gis-resources)
[State Land Board](http://www.trustlands.state.co.us/MapsandData/Pages/MapsAndData.aspx)
[Cottonwood Lake Campground](http://www.fs.usda.gov/recarea/psicc/recarea/?recid=12650)
[Geospatial Data](http://www.fs.usda.gov/main/psicc/landmanagement/gis)
[Maps and Publications](http://www.fs.usda.gov/main/psicc/maps-pubs)
[Rocky Mountain Region GIS Data Library](http://www.fs.usda.gov/detail/r2/landmanagement/gis/?cid=stelprdb5165938)
[Geospatial Library - External Resources](http://www.fs.usda.gov/detail/r2/landmanagement/gis/?cid=stelprdb5166819)

Comment: Some of them are outdated.

Comment: you're going to have to define what outdated means to you. outdated = expired? outdated = link rot?

Comment: When you click on a hyperlink and it opens nothing...so the link might be outdated or moved.

Comment: ....a link on which site? and what does nothing mean? you get a 404?

Answer (score 1):

If you have arcgis desktop go to add data from arcgisonline and search for campgrounds. some of the datasets mentioned here are there

if you dont have arcgis desktop just make a free arcgisonline account and search for the campground data that way